# Salesforce with Alexa: Get Salesforce Endpoint dynamically

Tags: oauth

There is a [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-a-private-alexa-for-business-skill-for-salesforce) example for Salesforce and Alexa. In this example Alexa link account function is used. It only returns the access token, nothing more. Is it possible to call a static url with an access token to get the instance url of an org?

**the not so obvious answer**
Handle OAuth yourself

Yes this is a solution, but does not use standard alexa functions and the oauth process in salesforce without the user secret is an visual process, which is not possible with the echo dot for example. You could use Alexa Cards with a Smartphone and the alexa app to enter your credentials and Secrets and then store them persistently in a database the skill has access to. But this process is so much more complex. There must be a way to determe the instance url, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hit the [UserInfo](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_using_userinfo_endpoint.htm&type=5) endpoint:

- Production: `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo`
- Sandbox: `https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo`

The response includes all service URLs (SOAP, REST, etc). Sample response (redacted for relevance):

```
{
   "organization_id": "00Dx000...",
   ...
   "urls":
   {
      "enterprise":"https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/{version}/00Dx00...",
      "partner":"https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/{version}/00Dx00...",
      "rest": "https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/",
      "sobjects": "https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/sobjects/",
      "search": "https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/search/",
      "query": "https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/query/",
      "recent": "https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/recent/",
      "profile": "https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/005x000...",
      "feeds": "https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/chatter/feeds",
      "groups": "https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/chatter/groups",
      "users": "https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/chatter/users",
      "feed_items": "https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/chatter/feed-items"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As part of the OAuth response back, you should have access to the identity URL. The response from hitting that identity URL should list the custom domain as per the documentation here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_using_openid.htm&type=5

Comment: Thats true, but if you use the alexa LinkAcccount Process you only get the accessToken, not the whole response itself.